# What is the best way to edit frontend in Magento 2?

Tags: javascript, html, magento, bootstrap-4, magento2

I have setup Magento 2 and I am using Luma theme with demo data and I want to edit layout (frontend) of homepage.

What I want to ask is what is the best way to edit frontend by writing code for it like including Bootstrap and jquery etc along with frontend code in some **ptml** block file and integrate it with page or update **block** file with your code like you could do in **wordpress**.

I have tried **Magento documentation** and some other blogs but could not find what is the best way to do it. I am new to Magento so sorry for such a naive question but it would be great if anyone helps me out here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for making changes in the frontend you need to create your own theme for creating a theme you can follow these steps from here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

it will guide you for creating a basic theme
and for making changes in blocks you need to create an extension and override that block here is the steps to create a basic extension in Magento 2

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-hello-world-module-magento-2.html

here are the steps to override the core blocks

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html

Comment: Kindly include in your answer the essential parts of the links. This is for the case that the provided links becomes unreachable

Comment: @nikunj what if i want to change layout of theme? is there any way i can do that?
thank you for your answer.

Comment: @nikunj just last thing what i want to do it is rather than changing layout through XML i want to do it through **HTML** code and include it using block on page.
can you be more specific on that?

Comment: for changing the HTML for a specific block you can do by overriding its "phtml" file to your custom theme if you want to move the block and do customization you should need to change in XML